# MyISAM: How to SELECT without lock-waiting with a running DELETE?

Tags: mysql, optimization, myisam

I have a table with 30 million records, using MyISAM engine. I have recurrent DELETE statements every 15 minutes to clean the table from old records.

Using:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=123;
```

while a 'DELETE FROM mytable...' is running (which takes from 30 - 60 seconds).

Will the SELECT statement return dirty records without locking? Or will the table lock be respected and wait 30 seconds then return the results? Is there a way to get a MyISAM table to return SELECT queries while DELETE has a table lock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The DELETE statement supports the
>   following modifiers:
>
> If you specify LOW_PRIORITY, the
>   server delays execution of the DELETE
>   until no other clients are reading
>   from the table. This affects only
>   storage engines that use only
>   table-level locking (such as MyISAM,
>   MEMORY, and MERGE).

u can use

```
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM mytable ......
```

Comment: Yes, but once the DELETE statement obtains the table lock, no SELECT statements can go thru for about 30 - 60 seconds (until completion).

Comment: @Amer For MyISAM tables, if you use the QUICK keyword, the storage engine does not merge index leaves during delete, which may speed up some kinds of delete operations.